# Map foreign key to scalar property

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I have 2 tables: `Data` and `AdditionalData`. Their relation is 1 to 1-0 (any `Data` can have 0 or 1 `AdditionalData`).

For main context I have classes:

```
class Data
{
    public long Id {get;set;} // PK
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public AdditionalData AdditionalData {get;set;} // can be null
}

class AdditionalData
{
    public long Id {get;set;} // PK
    public string AdditionalName {get;set;}
}
```

This works fine.

For another context I just need to know, whether `Data` has `AdditionalData` or not:

```
class ExtendedData
{
    public long Id {get;set;} //PK
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public bool HasAdditionalData {get;set;}
}
```

I can map it to view:

```
SELECT 
     d.*
    ,IIF(ad.Id IS NULL, 0, 1) AS HasAdditionalData
FROM Data AS d
LEFT OUTER JOIN AdditionalData AS ad ON d.Id = ad.Id
```

But I want to know:

Can I map `ExtendedData` class to tables without additional view?

Comment: @GertArnold no, in second context I heed `AdditionalData` for editing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A query like the one below might be what you are looking for, if you are ok with just using `ExtendedData` as the result of a projection:

`var result = ctx.Data.Select(d => new ExtendedData {Id = d.Id, Name = d.Name, HasAdditionalData = d.ApprovalStatus != null);`

The problem is that your PK is playing double duty as FK also, had you defined the FK for `AdditionalData` as another field, nullable `AdditionalDataId` perhaps, then checking for the existence of `AdditionalData` would be trivial; just check if `AdditionalDataId` is null, and you would get better performance also.

Comment: imagine that `AdditionalData` object is heavy (about 1mb), so it's very strange to load it from DB, just to check it's null or not null

Comment: @Backs Checking the FK (the AdditionalDataId property) will not load the object. Lazy loading is not triggered by just accessing the FK id property.

Comment: oh, i see, what you mean. yes, this can work, if I have additional column `AdditionalDataId` with unique values. It's a little bit complicated schema. But possible, yes

Comment: It's a 1 to min 0:max 1 relationship, right? So it should work fine. Make sure `AdditionalDataId` is optional (nullable) on the `Data` table.

Comment: Anyway, it looks like some sort of workaround. I have to add some unnecessary property in model

Comment: @Backs Without accessing the database, how else would the application tier knows if some other table has a row related to the row you are interested in?

Comment: I want, Entity Framework does it for me. Generate some additional sql-code to query for checking related data. Like in view I posted. Why not?

Comment: You could do as suggested by Klinger, but make the property private, and have a public property: bool HasAdditionalData => fk.HasValue;

Comment: @jannagy02 Making it private will prevent EF from populating the field. In any case, HasAdditionalData needs to be at least a computed property, defined in the table, so that it can be used in queries.

Comment: I accept this answer, because it's more simple in implementation

Answer (score 1):

You could avoid creation of database view with [DefiningQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj730307.aspx) construct. DefiningQuery provides the same functionality as database view, but it's defined in your model, not in the database itself.

You can't create `DefiningQuery` with Visual Studio Model Designer though, you should manually edit your edmx file. At first add `EntityType` and `EntitySet` definitions to SSDL layer:

```
<!-- SSDL content -->
<edmx:StorageModels>
<Schema Namespace="TestDataModel.Store" Provider="System.Data.SqlClient" ProviderManifestToken="2012" Alias="Self" xmlns:store="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/12/edm/EntityStoreSchemaGenerator" xmlns:customannotation="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2013/11/edm/customannotation" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm/ssdl">

  <EntityType Name="ExtendedData">
    <Key>
      <PropertyRef Name="Id" />
    </Key>
    <Property Name="Id" Type="bigint" Nullable="false" StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" />
    <Property Name="Name" Type="nvarchar(max)" Nullable="false" />
    <Property Name="HasAdditionalData" Type="bit" Nullable="false" />
  </EntityType>

  <EntityContainer Name="TestDataModelStoreContainer">
    <EntitySet Name="ExtendedData" EntityType="Self.ExtendedData" store:Type="Views" store:Schema="dbo" store:Name="ExtendedData">
      <DefiningQuery>
        SELECT d.Id, d.Name, CAST(IIF(ad.Id IS NULL, 0, 1) AS BIT) AS HasAdditionalData
        FROM Data AS d
        LEFT OUTER JOIN AdditionalData AS ad ON d.Id = ad.Id
      </DefiningQuery>
    </EntitySet>
  </EntityContainer>

</Schema></edmx:StorageModels>
```

Note that your View query is specified under `DefiningQuery` element with slight changes.

Then you should add `ExtendedData` entity to CSDL. This could be done with further manual editing of edmx or with Model Designer. Here how it looks finally:

```
<!-- CSDL content -->
<edmx:ConceptualModels>
  <Schema Namespace="TestDataModel" Alias="Self" annotation:UseStrongSpatialTypes="false" xmlns:annotation="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/annotation" xmlns:customannotation="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2013/11/edm/customannotation" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm">
    <EntityContainer Name="TestDataEntities2" annotation:LazyLoadingEnabled="true">
      <EntitySet Name="ExtendedDatas" EntityType="TestDataModel.ExtendedData" />
    </EntityContainer>
    <EntityType Name="ExtendedData">
      <Key>
        <PropertyRef Name="Id" />
      </Key>
      <Property Name="Id" Type="Int64" Nullable="false" annotation:StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" />
      <Property Name="Name" Type="String" Nullable="false" />
      <Property Name="HasAdditionalData" Type="Boolean" Nullable="false" />
    </EntityType>
  </Schema>
</edmx:ConceptualModels>
```

Then you should add CSDL-SSDL mapping, again manually editing edmx or through Table Mapping:

```
<!-- C-S mapping content -->
<edmx:Mappings>
  <Mapping Space="C-S" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/mapping/cs">
    <EntityContainerMapping StorageEntityContainer="TestDataModelStoreContainer" CdmEntityContainer="TestDataEntities2">
      <EntitySetMapping Name="ExtendedDatas">
        <EntityTypeMapping TypeName="IsTypeOf(TestDataModel.ExtendedData)">
          <MappingFragment StoreEntitySet="ExtendedData">
            <ScalarProperty Name="HasAdditionalData" ColumnName="HasAdditionalData" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="Name" ColumnName="Name" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="Id" ColumnName="Id" />
          </MappingFragment>
        </EntityTypeMapping>
      </EntitySetMapping>
    </EntityContainerMapping>
  </Mapping>
</edmx:Mappings>
```

**Be careful: Any manual changes in SSDL part of your edmx will be lost if you update your model from the database.**

Comment: Interesting solution, when you have edmx-file